# Changing PORT of a porcess in pm2

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, pm2

I have a process running in PORT 3000 and I want to deploy this process in any other PORT. How can I do this?

Comment: *What* process? How is its port configured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple configuration for pm2:

```js
module.exports = {
  apps : [
      {
        name: "myapp",
        script: "./app.js",
        watch: true,
        instance_var: 'INSTANCE_ID',
        env: {
            "PORT": 3000,
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        }
      }
  ]
}
```

There is an `apps.env.PORT` key you can use.

Comment: Note: This works only when the application supports setting the port. It's a quasi-standard to respect a `PORT` variable, but if you hardcode a port in your code then it won't help of course.

Comment: So there's no way to run the process in a port other than the one hardcoded port in the code?

Comment: @MuhammedRoshan PM2 is just executing a node program. Your node program is what decides the port. PM2 cannot override that but you can easily adjust your node app to accept configuration coming from PM2. Wherever you are setting 3000 for your app just set it to `apps.env.PORT` instead.

Answer (score 1):

PM2 does not decide your port, it's however the app PM2 is managing binds to the port is what you need to change.

Comment: In the app, port is set as 3000. What I wanted was to override this and run it on another port using pm2 or any other tool without changing code.

Comment: You would just set up your app to accept an environment variable to set the port or a flag and pass that through the PM2 start command or config.

Comment: @MuhammedRoshan For example `pm2 start myapp.js -- --myPort=4000` then just have your app set the port to the "myPort" argument value. You can also do this with environment variables or configurations.